Efficiently parse data in a flat file
I have a flat file containing data structured in a specific pattern, where each row consists of alternating fields. For example:
A|B
E|F|G|H
J|K|L|M

In this data, 'A' represents field 1, 'B' represents field 2, 'E' represents field 3, 'F' represents field 4, 'G' represents field 5, and 'H' represents field 6. The pattern repeats with 'J' representing field 3 again, 'K' representing field 4, 'L' representing field 5, and 'M' representing field 6.
I want to process this data in Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services (IICS). How can I map these fields in IICS? Can I use the fixed width format, or is there a better approach? What components should I use to handle this data structure effectively?

you can only used fixed width if the data is actually separated at fixed widths in the file (your sample data "a", "b", "c", etc. probably tells nothing about the actual data contained in the file. But in all cases it seems you will have real problems if data is on different rows. How would you know the first item in the row is a "A" item, or an "E" item, or a "J" item? Will you have to count/keep track of rows as you process them?
